# Calling Struct Values stored in List using STL and Call-by-Reference

Tags: c++

I'm learning how data structures work in C++ and am revising on my first lab session. I'm having a problem where I can't call values stored in a function. I can't figure out if the problem is that it's not stored in the list, I'm calling it the wrong way or I'm storing it in the wrong way. I've asked my lecturer for input and the code that I've written up is after receiving help from her but we never got to test the code in class.

I've tried pulling and reading up on examples on the internet but still ended up with the same problem even after revising the code multiple times. I understand that I could just leave this problem here because I will be learning about pointers and nodes in the future but a puzzle that I can't solve has always annoyed me and I'm not ashamed to ask for help.

Here is my code:

```
#include<list>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct Customer{
    string Name;
    int Quantity;
    float Payment;
    string Remark;
};

int menu() {
    
    int choice;
    cout << "::ROTI BOY PROGRAM MENU::\n";
    cout << "1. Add order\n";
    cout << "2. Display order\n";
    cout << "3. Exit program\n";
    cout << "Enter choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
    
}

void addOrder(list<Customer> *placeholder) {
    
    Customer data;
    
    cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
    cin >> data.Name;

    cout << "\nQuantity of buns: ";
    cin >> data.Quantity;

    cout << "\nExtra cheese (Y/N): ";
    cin >> data.Remark;

}

void displayOrder(Customer &data) {
    
    cout << "\nName: " << data.Name;
    cout << "\nQuantity: " << data.Quantity;
    
    if (data.Remark == "Y" || data.Remark == "y")
        data.Payment = data.Quantity*4.00;
    else 
        data.Payment = data.Quantity*3.00;
    cout << "\nTotal: " << data.Payment << endl;
    
    if (data.Remark == "Y" || data.Remark == "y")
        data.Remark = "Extra Cheese";
    else 
        data.Remark = "None";
        
    cout << "Remark: " << data.Remark << endl;

}




int main() {
    list<Customer>Record;
    Customer order;
    int choice;

    do {
        choice = menu();
        switch (choice) {
          case 1: 
            addOrder(&Record);
            Record.push_back(order);
            break;
            
          case 2: 
            cout << "\nRecords of Orders ";
            list <Customer>::iterator it = Record.begin(), end = Record.end();
            for (; it != end; ++it) {
                displayOrder(*it);
                cout << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 3);
}
 ``
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your `addOrder` function should probably be

```
void addOrder(list<Customer> *placeholder) {
    
    Customer data;
    
    cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
    cin >> data.Name;

    cout << "\nQuantity of buns: ";
    cin >> data.Quantity;

    cout << "\nExtra cheese (Y/N): ";
    cin >> data.Remark;

    placeholder->push_back(data);  // add your new value to the list
}
```

then you can update your `case` statement

```
  case 1: 
    addOrder(&Record);
    Record.push_back(order);  // <-- delete this line
    break;
```